# Shared element transitions between two activities in compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-animation

Is there currently anything that will allow to animate classic transition between the results list and details screen with shared element animation in Jetpack Compose?
Something like [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fandroid-developers.googleblog.com%2F2018%2F02%2Fcontinuous-shared-element-transitions.html&psig=AOvVaw3Id37tA-ZWWd4G6oSeSTKM&ust=1669108834797000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=2ahUKEwjlyeSK-b77AhVk8rsIHW6fDFAQjRx6BAgAEAo).

I know of some experimental libraries that allows that, but they all work on single activity and I was wondering of more traditional approach with 2 activities.

Comment: You might be interested checking this github repo
https://github.com/skydoves/Orbital

Answer (score 9):

The [official Jetpack Compose roadmap](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/compose-roadmap) states that shared element transition is currently in focus, so no official support yet.

Comment: still in focus :/

Comment: been in focus since at least July 2021 https://web.archive.org/web/20210728170345/https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/compose-roadmap