# How to navigate between screens with shared element?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I want to show a fullscreen popup dialog to display a user-scaleable image already displayed as a thumbnail in a list screen. How can I smoothly scale the image from the thumbnail, and return to its original position when I close it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shared element transitions between two activities in compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74516678/shared-element-transitions-between-two-activities-in-compose)

Comment: You might be interested checking this github repo
https://github.com/skydoves/Orbital, also commented this on the link mentioned by @Renz