# LazyColumn to LazyVerticalGrid and vice versa switch animation?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a button on my screen to switch between LazyColumn and LazyVerticalGrid but the twist is that I want items to animate while switching like below.

**How can I achieve the following behavior in Jetpack Compose as shown below?**

[image: ![Text](https://im3.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-3-d2131e9e11f0.gif)]

Answer (score 2):

You need to creat Composable function that wraps both `LazyColumn` and `LazyVerticalGrid`. You can use `Animatable` to control the transition progress.

```
        @Composable
        fun TransitionLazyColumnToGrid(
            items: List<String>,
            isGrid: Boolean,
            modifier: Modifier = Modifier
        ) {
            // Create an Animatable to control the transition progress
            val transitionProgress = remember { Animatable(0f) }

            // Use a Transition for animating the layout switch
            val transition = updateTransition(transitionProgress)

            val gridAlpha by transition.animateFloat(
                transitionSpec = { tween(durationMillis = 500) },
            ) { progress ->
                if (isGrid) 1f - progress else progress
            }

            // Use the AnimatedVisibility to control the visibility and layout of the components
            AnimatedVisibility(
                visible = !isGrid,
                enter = fadeIn(),
                exit = fadeOut(),
                modifier = modifier.then(Modifier.alpha(gridAlpha))
            ) {
                LazyColumn {
                    items(items) { item ->
                        // List item content
                    }
                }
            }

            AnimatedVisibility(
                visible = isGrid,
                enter = fadeIn(),
                exit = fadeOut(),
                modifier = modifier.then(Modifier.alpha(1f - gridAlpha))
            ) {
                LazyVerticalGrid(
                    cells = GridCells.Fixed(3),
                ) {
                    items(items) { item ->
                        // Grid item content
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

when user interaction to trigger the transition and update the `transitionProgress` value. For example, a `ToggleButton` to switch between the layouts:

```
        var isGrid by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

        ToggleButton(
            checked = isGrid,
            onCheckedChange = { isGrid = it }
        ) {
            Text(text = "Switch Layout")
        }

        TransitionLazyColumnToGrid(
            items = yourItemList,
            isGrid = isGrid,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        )
```

Comment: Can you please show the output of the above solution too?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **AnimatedVisibility**.

> The AnimatedVisibility composable animates the appearance and disappearance of its content.

I think 2 uses will be enough for your scenario.

```
var showGridDesign by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

AnimatedVisibility(
    visible = !showGridDesign,
    enter = yourEnterAnimation,
    exit = yourExitAnimation,
) {
    LazyColumn {
       // content
    }
}

AnimatedVisibility(
    visible = showGridDesign,
    enter = yourEnterAnimation,
    exit = yourExitAnimation,
) {
    LazyVerticalGrid() {
       // content
    }
}
```

You can use it as a source for sample animations.

[Sample Animations - Transitions](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation/composables-modifiers#built-in_animated_composables)

Sample Transition Effect

[image: AnimatedVisibility Sample]

[All Transitions Effect](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation/composables-modifiers#enter-exit-transition)

Comment: Thanks but Lazycolumn items are transforming (changing position) to make themself adjust in a grid view, i think `Animate visibility` can't do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for Shared element transitions, like in [this example](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/02/continuous-shared-element-transitions.html). Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74529043/22752098) it's not supported yet in Compose; the [official roadmap](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/compose-roadmap) says it's still "In Focus". I did find this [experimental library](https://github.com/skydoves/Orbital#shared-element-transition-with-multiple-items) that might do what you want.